# How to fetch json data from a url that requires an api key to access the data in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a web application using ReactJS - I am trying to fetch the data from a URL. In order to access the JSON data, an API key is required in order to access it. I have the API key, I'm struggling to understand how to fetch the data with the key. I have been told to use headers, so if someone can explain how headers work and how this can be achieved. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends, the API will tell you how to pass it exactly because it's up to them to decide how they want the authentication to be done. Usually it's either an `Authorization: Bearer` header or something custom like `X-API-Key` but it may also require you to cryptographically sign your request with the key, or something else entirely. Can you link to the API docs or copy the instructions you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP sends headers before the actual body of your request

```
GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3.org
Your-Custom-Header: Your-Api-Key

{
 ...
}
```

Note the double newline after the last given header.

The fetch API allows you to set custom headers, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch .

```js
fetch("your-url.com", {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'API-Header-Name-Here': 'Your API KEY'
    }
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
})
.then(() => ...);
```

EDIT:

I just saw the instructions your API service provider gave to you:

```js
fetch("https://your-url.com/link?key=your-api-key", {
    method: 'GET'
})
.then(() => ...);
```

Your API key should be supplied via `GET` query parameter `key`, not via header.

Comment: Hi Phillip, 

after attempting to try it this way, I am getting an error.

Error:
Access to fetch at 'https://www.interiorgoodsdirect.com/interview/api/products' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Seems like your API service does not set the correct CORS headers, which define access from other domain origins (such as localhost in your case).
You could try deleting the line `mode: 'cors'` from my example, maybe this already fixes your issue.

Comment: Btw, you should really urgently delete the API key in your comment section of your question.

Comment: i have deleted the mode:cors line and still the same error @philipp

Comment: Seems like the API service does not implement the correct CORS headers. You should contact them.

Comment: Philipp, my friend, you're a life saver. I missed your edited answer above. It now works pal, cheers for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with React. You have to check the documentation of the `fetch` implementation you're using, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation of your API. It should specify how you send the API key with your requests. You usually put your API key in the header of a request but in order to see which header you are going to use, you should check the API documentation.